# Is it possible to send Intent after 5 minutes in android?

Tags: android

I am new in android. Please tell me whether it is possible to send Intent after 5 minute, 10 minutes in android?
How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By sending an Intent you mean start an activity?

Comment: ya i want start activity after 5 min

Answer (score 7):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Launch new Intent here
  }
}, ((1000 * 60) * 5)); // 5 minutes delay before execute run()
```

Comment: but in run() what content I can write?

Comment: @user1371813 Inside `run()` you would put your code to start your Activity.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 3):

see below code it may help you. use this timer for 5 minute.

```
 final Timer myt = new Timer();
    myt.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
      Intent intent= new Intent(currentActivity.this, new_activity.class);
      startActivity(intent);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    }

      myt.cancel();
    }
    }, 300000);
```

*in above code after call intent timer terminated automatically.*

Answer (score 0):

Hm this can go bad if the OS decides to kill your app at some point. If you will really need that intent to still be passed after 5 minutes, you should use alarms. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18827407/1665562)

Answer (score -2):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 Intent intent= new Intent(youractivity.this, activitytostart5minuteslater.class);
 startActivity(intent);
}
}, ((1000 * 60) * 5));
```

did you ever read the comments???

Comment: Actually, I did. And you didn't. ;-) Your edit shows that doesn't it.

Comment: He asked what content can ı write inside of it and i answered that. But you wouldnt understand it, its ok. :)