# run service even if the application is closed (killed)

Tags: android, service, background

I want that this service run even if the application is closed (kiiled) or even if the user dont start the app.
i want the service start after the application is installed and from this point, the service should run always.

```
public class notifications extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
        }

        @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable runb = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runb, 0);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
}*/

public class notifications extends IntentService
{
        private Timer mBackGroundTimer;
        public notifications()
    {
        super("myservice");
        this.mBackGroundTimer=new Timer();
    }
        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mBackGroundTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                        Notification("This is message from Dipak Keshariya (Android Application Developer)", "This is Android Notification Message");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },1000, 2000);
    } // END onHandleIntent()
        private void mStopTimer()
    {
        //Call this whenever you need to stop the service
        mBackGroundTimer.cancel();
    }

        private void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            android.app.Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Message from Dipak Keshariya (Android Developer)!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
        }
}
```

how i can do that?

Comment: read this one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html   and this one  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 11):

Looking at your code, it appears you want your service to periodically give notifications.

As far as having it run continuously goes, keep in mind that by design, the Android system may terminate your service process at any time. You can influence this a bit, but you cannot prevent the system from killing your service.

So for your periodical actions, it would be best to use AlarmManager with a recurring alarm. Your service would then basically be one-shot, i.e. perform the action once and then exit.

For some code, look here for example:

[Android: Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018111/android-alarm-manager)

Comment: So i put this on my mainactivity and it's start the service, and even if i kill the application the service not stop to running?

Comment: It will register an alarm, which will periodically start your service. Your service will not need to be running all the time (in fact, your service should just exit after you have performed the desired action once), as you can set the alarm to trigger a single service run whenever it is needed. No need for your application to be running either.

Comment: I want to send notification when X append, but the X is on a web site (json). so i need to run the service always and then if X append i want to send notification. and it's need to run always. even if i not start the application.

Comment: Well, with the alarm manager approach, your service will not need to be running all the time. The only thing your service needs to do when executed is check for your condition X once, and if true send your notification. The alarm manager will take care of calling your service every x seconds, which is essentially the same as having your service always running. The benefit is, you do not need to worry about the android system killing your service process, as it will be restarted every time the task needs to be done. Even if your app is not running, since alarm manager dont depend on your app.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement the OnStartCommand method of the Service class and in it, return Service.START_STICKY. That will do the trick. If you kill the application, the service will continue to run in the background. However, if you restart your phone, I think you need to implement something else in your app, as well, a boot service or something like that.

Comment: I don't think you can start a service without starting the application first. But with START_STICKY, after you started your service, it won't stop.

Comment: But my requirement is i have to start service after application start.ex after login.

Answer (score 1):

As you requirement is to run the service in the background. you are on the right track to use the service because this is meant for background running purpose only.

from the activitiy you can start the service by

```
startService(new Intent(activityName.this, serviceName.class));
```

or if your application is not having any activity then you can make the service as default and main launcher of the application by putting

```
<service android:name="name of the service" >
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Comment: yes, but if i kill the application or restart the smartphone, the service is stop working, but i want him to run always..

Comment: Killing application and restart the device is two different thing. you can put one broadcast receiver when the phone is started again, you can start your service. and make your service as sticky so system will not kill it.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer to this question is this : https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Sync Adapters introduced in Google I/O 2013.