# Cannot create an object for SQLiteOpenHelper from AsyncTask thread?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have to create an object for SQLiteOpenHelper from AsyncTask thread.
If I use `this` as the `Context` parameter, I'm getting an error -  `it cannot be applied`.

Here are my classes :

**MySQLiteHelper.java**

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {

    // the constructor takes Context as argument
}

}
```

**Parsing.java**

```
public class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected void onPreExecute() {

  MySQLiteHelper obj  = new MySQLiteHelper(this); 
  //cannot create  this object. 
 // which `Context` should I pass as an argument

    }

    // some code
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Parsing obj = new Parsing(context);

        obj.execute();

    }
}
```

**Answer to my question :** 
The method suggested by ZygoteInit as in marked answer, worked out. 
ρяσѕρєя K, in 3rd comment below that answer explained the same in code.

**EDIT :**

*This EDIT isn't much related to the question. [ZygoteInit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3287204/zygoteinit) is helping me with the overall approach of my problem.*

This is what I'm doing. I'm new to Android. Not sure if this can be mode more simple.

I want a piece of code to be executed for every few hours. So, I used [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. I dealt with all related stuff on it. The `AlarmReceiver` class gets called for every 4 hours. I want to put my code in that class. But since, the code involves Networking i.e. downloading some data, I learnt that it is recommended to use AsyncTask. So, I created another class `Parsing` which extends `AsyncTask`. Now, I need to store the data obtained during that Networking operation which is performed in `Parsing` class. So, I created `MySQLiteHelper` class.

Can I make it more simple folks?
My Aim : To perform a background networking operation for every few hours, which involves database.

Initially I used `service`. But, I want my code to get executed for every four hours even if the app is closed. So, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827085/run-service-even-if-the-application-is-closed-killed) to use an alarm manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `AsyncTask` class is defined inside an `Activity`, then use `MyActivity.this` as the `Context`, else pass a `Context` instance in the constructor.

**EDIT:**

Having read your question, I have understood your requirement. Instead of using a `BroadcastReceiver`, create a `Service` with your `PendingIntent` (i.e. use `getService()` instead of `getBroadcast()`) and perform your web service and database operations in it. From a `Service` you will get a valid `this` instance for `Context`.

Comment: What is Context instance in my case, please?

Comment: @ZygoteInit : i think `Parsing` is separate class so `MyActivity.this` will not work OP need to pass context from Activity to `Parsing` then from `Parsing` to `MySQLiteHelper`

Comment: @nikhil: add `private Context mContext; public Parsing(Context mContext){this.mContext=mContext}` in `Parsing` class and creating `Parsing` object from Activity by passing `MyActivity.this` like `Parsing objParsing=new Parsing(MyActivity.this);objParsing.execute();`

Comment: @nikhil: and then use `MySQLiteHelper obj  = new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);` in `onPreExecute`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK That's good. But MyActivity.this did not work.  I have to instantiate Parsing class from a Brodcast Receiver, so passed that context.

Comment: @nikhil: then pass context in place of `MyActivity.this` which is first parameter in onReceive method

Comment: Yep, that's what I did and no errors. Will execute and check it out soon :)

Comment: @nikhil: if your `AsyncTask` is being triggered by a `BroadcastReceiver`, where will the `onPostExecute()` method run ?? Or are you making use of only `doInBackground()` ?

Comment: @nikhil: and also, I think you need to use `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @ZygoteInit: I think OP need to use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: I was thinking the same thing

Comment: I added an edit to my question @ZygoteInit. When I call execute() method of AsyncTask all the three methods - onPreExecute
(), doInBackground(), onPostExecute() gets called.

Comment: @nikhil: try to reframe your question so that we can better help you. tell us what exactly you are trying to do. also, i dont think it is possible for all those three methods to be called at once. what makes you think so ??

Comment: @ZygoteInit The purpose of my question is solved. So, didn't change the question. But I'm not sure my approach to solving my task is right?

Comment: @ZygoteInit Initially I used service. But, I want my code to get executed for every four hours even if the app is closed. So, I read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827085/run-service-even-if-the-application-is-closed-killed to use an alarm manager.

Comment: @nikhil: so you are creating a `PendingIntent` with the `getBroadcast()` method, right ?? Similarly, you can also use `PendingIntent.getService()` and add this `PendingIntent` to the `AlarmManager`. This will start your `Service` every 4 hours. Just look for a tutorial on how to start a service with alarmmanager

Comment: Yes, I'm using GetBroadcast(). Okay, will do it. But, one last question - what is the downside of using BrodcastReceiver in my case? Will I not get a valid context by doing that? Thanks for you time. :)

Comment: The `this` provided by a `Service` is the correct context - besides, how can you run `AsyncTask` and web service from a `BroadcastReceiver` ? A `Service` is the correct way to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

create a field `private Context mContext` and in your `constructor` assign it to the `context` as: `this.mContext = context` and use `mContext` instead of `this`

From your example (hardcoded not tested, so you just understand the logic):

```
    public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mContext;

      public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      protected void onPreExecute() {

      MySQLiteHelper obj  = new MySQLiteHelper(mContext); 
      //cannot create  this object. 
      // which `Context` should I pass as an argument

      }

        // some code
    }

   }
```

But i would suggest that instead of creating an `instance` of `MySqliteHelper` on `onPreExecute()` method, you create an `instance` of that in your `activity/fragment` or whatever you use, and then access it on `onPreExecute()` whenever you want like so:

```
public YourClass extends Activity{ 
private MySQLiteHelper obj;
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    obj  = new MySQLiteHelper(this); 
}
 private class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
  //access obj here
  obj.whateverMethodYouWantToAccess
 }
}
```

If for some specific case you want to access it from another `class` than create a *public method* where you can get the `context` from and call that method when you want to get that `context`. Like so:

```
public Context geContext(){
 return mContext
}
```

If you are facing problem creating a MySqliteHelper instance for some reasen than make mContext `public static Context mContext` and access it directly like `MySQliteHelper.mContext`

Comment: Did not work! mContext cannot be accesed from  Parsing class.

Comment: @nikhil see my updated answer for accessing it from another class

Comment: Nice work @hrskrs But I'm still getting the same error, since I cannot use a private member of other class in Parsing class.

Comment: @nikhil make it `public static` if you want to access it from another class

Comment: Okay, but value does mContext have when passing. Default value right?

Comment: @nikhil yeah ofc (but give `this` value as default otherwise youll get NPE), but i would suggest you put that `async task` inside the `activity/fragment` class and create an instance of MySQliteHelper on `OnCreate()` method and then reference to it from `onPostExecute()` that way you will avoid NPE also

Comment: Nice. But how can I put AsyncTask inside activity class. I'm new to Android. But will work on ur suggestion soon. :) Thanks @hrskrs

Comment: @nikhil i have updated the answer with an example of it

Comment: I loved the approach @hrskrs. Trying it. Will get to you, if I have any problems. :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the ParsingActivty class reference to MySQLiteHelper for which you will do this

```
 public class ParsingActivty extends Activity 
 {
 Context context;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     context=this;
 }
```

and in Parsing.java

```
public class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected void onPreExecute() {

  MySQLiteHelper obj  = new MySQLiteHelper(context); 

}

// some code
}
```

And in MySQLiteHelper.java

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {

// the constructor takes Context as argument
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass a Context in the constructor of your AsyncTask, or use a static variable in your Application class to access it (set sMyInstace = this;). The first solution is preferable though.