# Run Async Task when app is closed only

Tags: android, asynchronous

I would like to run an async task when the app is closed out and only then. I tried putting it in the onDestroy() method but it only gets called sometimes (such as when the app is crashed). I also tried to put it on the onPause() method, but it also runs when the user tries to look at a different app rather than only when the app closes. Thanks!

Sincerely, Rocky

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593115/run-code-when-android-app-is-closed-sent-to-background and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747803/running-code-on-program-exit-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827085/run-service-even-if-the-application-is-closed-killed

Comment: Tried calling `finish()` on `onBackPressed()`  and checked `onDestroy()`  getting called?

Comment: use service to run in background ..

Comment: i think this will give you a good idea http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Thread` instead of `AsyncTask`, but if you want to use `AsyncTask` you'll need to do the following:

1. Don't update the UI in `AsyncTask` because `onDestroy` removes the resources and context for that activity. It will crash if you try to update them.
2. Use the application `Context` not the activity `Context` when you create your `AsyncTask`, because the activity `Context` is invalid after the activity is destroyed.