# how can i run cordova app even user close the app

Tags: android, cordova

want create app cordova and ionic for android to alaram in some times like 2:50 and I want program run even close the program I use katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin, but when I close program, it be close and don't still run in background this is code Example I used:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
    title:  'TheTitleOfYourProcess',
    text:   'Executing background tasks.'
  });

  // Enable background mode
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

  // Called when background mode has been activated
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
    // Set an interval of 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)
    setInterval(function () {
      var dd = new date();
      var h = dd.getHours();
      var m = dd.getMinutes();
      if(h == 2 && m ==50){
        alert("2:50");
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
}, false);
```

how can I make app still run even user close the program like , alarm clock or some program reminder ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run service even if the application is closed (killed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827085/run-service-even-if-the-application-is-closed-killed)

Comment: that is native i need some thing in cordova @manolodewin

Comment: You can use background service: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1041

Comment: which platform you are targeting ?

Comment: android @arpit Vasani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to use background-mode plugin. use this

https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

it based on  [katzer's local-notification plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

here is the [example repo](https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-notification-alarm-sample)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `config.xml` to enable background activity

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
```

Comment: what does this do..? Does it keep my app running background even if my app is killed

Comment: NO. Your app is still executed even if your app isn't the active(displayed on screen) application on your device